# How does Rust find out the upper limit of an iterator?

Tags: rust

I'm going through a couple of Rust examples, and there's a particular snippet of code which I don't really understand how it works. In particular, [this example](http://rustbyexample.com/fn/hof.html) of Higher Order Functions. My focus is on this snippet of code:

```
let sum_of_squared_odd_numbers: u32 =
    (0..).map(|n| n * n)             // All natural numbers squared
         .take_while(|&n| n < upper) // Below upper limit
         .filter(|n| is_odd(*n))     // That are odd
         .fold(0, |sum, i| sum + i); // Sum them
```

Here are my questions:

1. How does the compiler know when `(0..)` ends?  Is the loop unrolled at compile time and are all the lambdas evaluated?
2. Isn't this extremely memory inefficient compared to the imperative version?  For example `(0..).map(|n| n * n)` alone would end up taking O(n) memory.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> How does the compiler know when `(0..)` ends?

The compiler doesn't know at all. That is a range literal, specifically a [`RangeFrom`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/struct.RangeFrom.html). Note that it implements the [`Iterator`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html) trait. The core piece of `Iterator` is [`next`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#tymethod.next):

```
fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item>
```

That is, given a mutable borrow to the iterator, it can return another item (`Some`) or signal that there are no more items (`None`). It is completely possible to have iterators that [go on forever](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/fn.repeat.html).

In this particular example:

- The range will yield every unsigned 32-bit number before stopping <sup>†</sup>.
- The `map` will stop when the underlying iterator stops.
- The `take_while` will stop when the predicate fails or the underlying iterator stops.
- The `filter` will stop when the underlying iterator stops.
- The `fold` will stop when the underlying iterator stops.

> Isn't this extremely memory inefficient compared to the imperative version?

Nope! In fact, the compiler is very likely to compile this to the same code as the imperative version! You'd want to check the LLVM IR or assembly to be 100% sure, but Rust's monomorphization capabilities combined with LLVM's optimizer do some pretty amazing things.

Each *iterator adapter* pulls just enough items from the previous adapter to calculate the next value. In your example, I'd expect a constant memory allocation for the entire process.

The only component of the pipeline that requires any extra space would be the `fold`, and it just needs an accumulator value that is an `u32`. All the other adapters have no extra state.

An important thing to note is that calling the `map`, `filter`, and `take_while` iterator adaptors doesn't do any iterator computation at that point in time. They simply return new objects:

```
// Note the type is
// Filter<TakeWhile<Map<RangeFrom<_>, [closure]>, [closure]>, [closure]>
let () = 
    (0..)
    .map(|n| n * n)            
    .take_while(|&n| n < 20)
    .filter(|n| n % 2 == 0);
// At this point, we still haven't even looked at a single value
```

Whenever you call `next` on the final adaptor, each layer of the adaptor stack does enough work to get the next value. In the original example, `fold` is an *iterator terminator* that consumes the entire iterator, calling `next` until there are no more values.

**†** As [bluss points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32790281/how-does-rust-find-out-the-upper-limit-of-an-iterator#comment53420982_32790665), you don't really want to try and go past the maximum value of a range, as it will either [panic or loop forever](http://is.gd/KVCRDP), depending on if it is built in debug or release mode.

Comment: What the end of `0..` is, is kind of a trick question. It ends with a debug assertion for overflow. Deduction: Make sure less elements than that are pulled out.

Comment: For those coming from imperative languages, is it more accurate to think of the sequence as `fold(filter(take_while(map(0...))))`  as opposed to `a = map(); b = take_while(a) ; ...`?

Comment: @R.D. In languages I've used, those are equivalent pieces of code. I added another paragraph that might help in understanding. Unfortunately, there's no built-in direct equivalent I am aware of for C or C++.

Comment: In other words, Rust iterators use a "pull" model, not a "push" one.

Comment: @Shepmaster thanks for the brilliant edits.  It went a long way in me understanding Lazy evaluation.  Am I correct in noting that this really has nothing to do with Rust?  I think one could return lazily evaluated iterator in other imperative languages like Java and still achieve similar results.

Comment: @R.D. you mean like [Java's Iterator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html) ^_^? Yes, it's nothing unique to Rust, but I might argue that many of the things that Rust provides combine to make iterators especially nice in Rust. For example, the `for` loop is based on iterators making it clean to integrate, and the generics without extra overhead make it efficient to use them more frequently.

Answer (score 2):

The compiler doesn't know when `(0..)` ends.  However the iterators are lazy (as is mentioned on the page you linked to) and the the `.take_while(|&n| n < upper)` statement will stop the sequence as soon as `n` is greater than or equal to `upper`

Answer (score 0):

I am not a rust expert, but the comment

```
// All natural numbers squared
```

tells me, that the list (or stream, enumeration, whatever) cannot be fully evaluated. So I would put my bet on some kind of lazy evaluation.

In that case, the range would carry an internal state and upon every usage the next element is computed. Catamorphisms (fold, map) are then implemented by "storing" the respective implementation instead of evaluating it directly.

**update**: I overlooked the `take_while` part. This method seems to be responsible (also according to the comment), to actually force the evaluation. Everything before just computes the range abstract, i.e. without any concrete elements. This is possible because functions can be composed.

The standard example for such a behavior is [haskell](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/infinite-list-tricks-in-haskell/)

Comment: Do you mean to say that `let foo = (0..).map(|n| n * n); let bar = foo.take_while(...); bar` is compiled differently than `let bar = (0..).map(|n| n * n).take_while(...)`?

Comment: Haskell is a bit of an odd example, since it uses implicit thunks and acts at a more "high level" than Rust. A more obvious example would be something like Ocaml's lazy lists, which are just `Nil | Cons of 'a * (unit -> 'a stream)`. The main difference being Haskell's laziness is something that happens to your code, whereas explicit laziness is something you make from your code.

Comment: `take_while` is not responsible. `map`, `take_while`, `filter` are adaptors that take and return lazy iterators. `fold` is the consumer, it takes an iterator and produces a value. `take_while`'s role is that it can end the stream if its predicate fails.